# Hadoop HDFS Data File : Displaying Datanodes & Blocks

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

I've put a file into HDFS, and I want to know precisely how it was scattered through the DFS (Which Blocks are in which datanodes).

Tried fsck but I get an "invalid path" error when I specify the name of the data file that' i've put in the DFS.

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
hdfs fsck /path/to/file -files -blocks -locations
```

This will print out locations for every block of the file.

Namenode Web UI also would provide this information. Under `Utilities --> Browse the file system`, Select the file to view the Block Information.

Comment: Thanks. I have seen this option but my file that i have put on HDFS (called "datafile") results in an "invalid path" error with the fsck command `hdfs fsck datafile`

Comment: You have to provide the complete path. You can do a find to know where the file is `hdfs dfs -find  / -name datafile -print`

Comment: the find command returns the error the following `find: Permission denied: user=root, access=READ_EXECUTE` (has to do with hdfs user ownership...)

Comment: Yes, you are logged in as root. You should be running the command as the Hdfs superuser. If you do not who is the hdfs user is, run `hdfs dfs -ls /`, the superuser name will be listed in the file permissions. Login as that user to execute hadoop commands.